# Eloquent ORM dynamic relation properties vs method for eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent in the Slim framework. Now I would like to take advantage of eager loading. I wonder is there is a difference between using the property and the method.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm using the twig template engine and I only can call a method.

Will I only be able to take advantage of eager loading using the property or not?

```
$obj = new Book();
$books = $books->with('author')->get();

// Using the property
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author->name;
}

// Using the method
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author()->get()->name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a huge difference. In the second line you are already populated your `$books` with their authors. And when you are iterating through them in the first foreach you already have all the data, so you don't perform any additional sql queries. This is what eager loading made for.

But in the second foreach you are calling `get()` method on every iteration and Laravel starts repopulating authors making queries over and over for every book.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, that's what I was afraid for. Would it help if I made a method in my Book model like 'authorData' which returns the author property. And call the 'authorData method'. That way I can call the property in my Twig template. Will I get the same results as the first foreach?